# How to build multi arch docker images with github CI without general failure if single architecture fails?

Tags: docker, github-cli, buildx

I am trying to stop my github CI from failing completely in case the build of a multi-arch docker images is successful for at least on architecture such that the successful builds of the those architectures are still pushed to docker hub. What I do so far:

```
name: 'build images'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    tags:
      - '*'
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 4 1 * *'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Prepare
        id: prep
        run: |
          DOCKER_IMAGE=${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*/}
          VERSION=latest
          # If this is git tag, use the tag name as a docker tag
          if [[ $GITHUB_REF == refs/tags/* ]]; then
            VERSION="${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/v}"
          fi
          TAGS="${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${VERSION}"
          # If the VERSION looks like a version number, assume that
          # this is the most recent version of the image and also
          # tag it 'latest'.
          if [[ $VERSION =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
            TAGS="$TAGS,${DOCKER_IMAGE}:latest"
          fi
          # Set output parameters.
          echo ::set-output name=tags::${TAGS}
          echo ::set-output name=docker_image::${DOCKER_IMAGE}
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
        with:
          platforms: all

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Inspect builder
        run: |
          echo "Name:      ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.name }}"
          echo "Endpoint:  ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.endpoint }}"
          echo "Status:    ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.status }}"
          echo "Flags:     ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.flags }}"
          echo "Platforms: ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.platforms }}"
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          builder: ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.name }}
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.prep.outputs.tags }}
      - name: Sync
        uses: ms-jpq/sync-dockerhub-readme@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          repository: xx/yy
          readme: "./README.md"
```

What I also did is: create this CI for each architecture individually with an own architecture tag but that way, I do not have a "multi-arch" tag..